# How can I the size of an image file from the URL?

Tags: php, filesize

Images and script are hosted on the same account (one site), but we know only the URL of the image.

```
$image = "http://example.com/images/full-1091.jpg"
```

How can we get the **size** of this file?

Pseudo-code:

```
{ do something with $image and get $image_size }
echo $image_size;
```

I would prefer `$image_size` to be formatted in human-readable file sizes, like "156,8 Kbytes" or "20,1 Mbytes".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function like this:

```
echo filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
```

You can also format the unit of the size with this function:

```
function format_size($size) {
      $sizes = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
      if ($size == 0) { return('n/a'); } else {
      return (round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $sizes[$i]); }
}
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, this answer perpetuates the confusion between decimal and binary abbreviations for multiples. Is a megabyte 1,000,000 bytes or 1,048,576 bytes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix I'd suggest either changing $sizes to array(" Bytes", " KiB", " MiB", " GiB", " TiB", " PiB", " EiB", " ZiB", " YiB"), or changing the two occurrences of 1024 to 1000.

Answer (score 3):

> Images and script hosted on the same account (one site).

Then don't use a URL: Use the direct file path and [`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize).

Comment: I would say that this is the correct solution for files local to the same server as a solution for looking up files via url is quite a bit uglier and longer so it should only be used for remote files: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462

Answer (score 3):

**Please Note:**

The result of **filesize()** function are cached!
Use **clearstatcache()** to clear the cache...

source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filesize.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo filesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/full-1091.jpg");
```

note that `http://site.com/images/full-1091.jpg` **is not** a file

as for the formatted output  ("156,8 Kbytes" or "20,1 Mbytes") try to help yourself and use search. There is a ton of answers to this question already.

Comment: @Pekka use the file path means "use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']" ?

Comment: @Ignatz it's one option - or use the hard-coded full path (`/path/to/folder/images/image.jpg`)

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php
  $contents=file_get_contents("http://site.com/images/full-1091.jpg");
   // var_dump($contents);
//  $fp =fopen("1.jpeg","w");
  file_put_contents("1.jpeg",$contents);
  $size= filesize("1.jpeg");
  echo $size."in Bytes";
  ?>
```

Check this it can work for you

Comment: dude, it is ugliest solution I have ever seen.

Comment: The solution would be correct (except it is saving the content in 1.jpeg, and trying to get the file size of 1.gif), if the PHP code is running is a server that is different from http://site.com. If the PHP code is running on http://site.com too, then it should directly call `filesize()` passing the image file path. As the OP didn't report if the PHP code is running on the same server that contains the image, this solution is valid too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you can't read. `Images and script hosted on the same account.(one site).` You'd better limit your hobbies to sci-fi.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel: I am wearing eyeglasses; what is your excuse to answer to a question with "try to help yourself and use search"? Then, the debate of a file not being a file doesn't make entirely sense, if we are not talking of a resource accessed through HTTP protocol.

Comment: @kiam here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq `Please do look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask.` And talking of questions, a developer who cannot tell what is a file, is good for nothing. To understand basic principles is way more important than ability to copy and paste a code cnippet someone wrote for you on SO. For what most of you, SO users, take programming for.

Comment: I don't know if the OP understands what a file; the only thing I can say it doesn't make sense to access a file locale to the server using http://example.com/filename.extension. I think that who asks a question deserves an explanation of why he is doing the wrong thing; simply saying that is wrong without to exactly explain why it is wrong it is like to copy a code snippet without to know what it does.