# How to make curl call for remote url which contain space

Tags: php, curl

This question is continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909565/php-filesize-not-working-for-url-cdn-url)

```
<?php

    $remoteFile = 'http://cdn/bucket/my textfile.txt';
    $ch = curl_init($remoteFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //not necessary unless the file redirects (like the PHP example we're using here)
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($data)
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($data === false) {
      echo 'cURL failed';
      exit;
    }

    $contentLength = 'unknown';
    $status = 'unknown';
    if (preg_match('/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/', $data, $matches)) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
      $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    echo 'HTTP Status: ' . $status . "\n";
    echo 'Content-Length: ' . $contentLength;
    ?>
```

I am using above code to get the file size in server side from `CDN url`  but when I use the CDN url with space in it. it is throwing below error

```
page not found  09/18/2014 - 16:54  http://cdn/bucket/my textfile.txt
```

**Can I make curl call for remote url which contain space ?**

> To give **little bit more info** on this
>
> I am having interface where user will be saving file to CDN (so user
>   can give whatever title user want, it may contain space )and all
>   information in saved in back end db.  I have another interface where I
>   retrieve the  saved information and show it in my page along with file
>   size which I am getting using above code.

Comment: Have you tried: `http://cdn/bucket/my+textfile.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode your url's which have space's in it.

```
echo urlencode('http://cdn/bucket/my textfile.txt');
```

Ref: [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

or you can use,

```
echo '<a href="http://example.com/department_list_script/',
rawurlencode('sales and marketing/Miami'), '">';
```

Ref: [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to URL / URI encode

In an encoded URL, the spaces are encoded as: %20, so your URL would be: `http://cdn/bucket/my%20textfile.txt` so you could just use this url.

Or as this is PHP, you could use the urlencode function.
ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

e.g.

$remoteFile = urlencode('http://cdn/bucket/my textfile.txt');

or

$ch = curl_init(urlencode($remoteFile));

Comment: I understand you are new to stackoverflow . Please refer this for answering http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer